# $|P(A)| = 2^{|A|}$ question

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For the following question:

Let $A = \{ 1,2,3,4,5 \}$, $B = \{ a,b,c,d,e \}$, and $C = \{ \text{red} , \text{green} , \text{blue} \}$.  Calculate $| \mathcal{P} ( A \times B \times C ) |$.

I know $|P(A)| = 2^{|A|}$

So am I right in thinking ... $5\times5\times3 = 75 = 2^{75}$ would be my answer?

Comment: Note that »$5 \times 5 \times 3 = 75 = 2^{75}$« doesn't really make sense ($75 \neq 2^{75}$).  Better to say something along the lines of »$A \times B \times B$ has size $5 \times 5 \times 3 = 75$, and therefore....«

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea. The only problem is saying that $5\times 5\times 3=75=2^{75}$. Instead, notice that $|A|=5$, $|B|=5$, and $|C|=3$. We know that $|A\times B\times C|=75$ by the definition of Cartesian Product. Thus $|\mathcal{P}(A\times B\times C)|=2^{75}$.